# How are numpy arrays handled in arithmetic? Python to C#

Tags: python, c#, arrays, numpy, translate

I am attempting to translate two functions from Python to C#. The first, `two_body_ode`, applies Newton's Universal Law of Gravitation:

```
def two_body_ode( state ):
    # Newtons Universal Law of Gravitation
    # earth_mu is a float = 3.9860043543609598E+05

    r = state[ :3 ]
    a = -earth_mu * r / np.linalg.norm( r ) ** 3

    return np.array( [ state[ 3 ], state[ 4 ], state[ 5 ],
             a[ 0 ], a[ 1 ], a[ 2 ] ] )
```

It takes a numpy array of six floats, the first three representing the x, y, and z dimensions of the position vector `r`, and the last three representing the dimensions of the velocity vector, `v`. The `r` vector is separated into its own array which is used directly in the equation below it to define the current `a` vector (acceleration) and finally the `v` and `a` vectors are combined and returned as a new six-item state array.

The second function, `rk4_step`, is an implementation of a fourth-degree Runge-Kutta method for tracing the velocity and acceleration vectors to their corresponding position and velocity vectors at the next time step. This function returns a six-item array of floats:

```
def rk4_step( f, y, h ):
    # Calculate one RK4 step
    # two_body_ode is passed for f
    # y is the current six-item state array
    # h is the step size, float 100.0 seconds

    k1 = f( y )
    k2 = f( y + 0.5 * k1 * h )
    k3 = f( y + 0.5 * k2 * h )
    k4 = f( y +       k3 * h )

    return y + h / 6.0 * ( k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4 )
```

`rk4_step` exists in a `for` loop which iterates through each row in the `states` array (`states = np.zeros( ( 60, 6 ) )`) and propagates the orbit.

How does Python handle numpy arrays being passed as variable values in equations? Is the equation evaluated for each item in the array and the results reassembled and returned as a new array?

Below is my attempt at translating `two_body_ode` to C#:

```
public static State Two_Body_Ode(State state, double mu) {
    Vector3d r = state.r;
    Vector3d a;
    a.x = -mu * r.x / Math.Pow(r.normalized.x, 3);
    a.y = -mu * r.y / Math.Pow(r.normalized.y, 3);
    a.z = -mu * r.z / Math.Pow(r.normalized.z, 3);
    return new State(state.v, a);
}
```

I created a struct called `State` which itself contains two structs called `Vector3d`, `r`, and `v`. A `Vector3d` is made up of three `double` values representing x, y, and z, resulting in a `State` containing six double values similar to the six floats used in the Python state array.

I ran a sample state `[6828.0, 0, 0, 0, 7.640506124372221, 0]` through both equations and these were the results:

`two_body_ode` in Python: `[0, 7.64050612, 0, -0.0085497, 0, 0]` (the correct output)

`Two_Body_Ode` in C#: `[0, 7.64050612437222, 0, -2721643787.25, NaN, NaN]`

During the above testing, I realized that the Python function wouldn't work if I substituted my own values in a list; it had to be a numpy array.

My ultimate question then: How are numpy arrays handled in Python (as opposed to simple lists) and how can I replicate their behavior in C#?

Comment: Like [this](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.html).

Comment: No idea about your actual question. I think it is a great idea to use Vector3d and a state-type. But you should [overload operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading) for your Vector3d-type so you can multiply and divide your vector with a scalar.

Comment: It looks like you know what math problem you want to solve. So just take the language of choice and solve the math problem in that language with the tools of that language? Why taking the solution in one language and trying to replicate that in another? Mostly it will end in a solution that will feel foreign in that language.

Comment: I think your problem is that you're not taking the norm of the entire vector.  I could be wrong but I believe that `np.linalg.norm` is going to return a single value and not an array.  I don't know what your `normalized` values are but that's likely the issue since the y and z values are 0 and that will result in division by 0.

Comment: Here's how you can get the norm of your vector `var norm = Math.Sqrt(r.x*r.x + r.y*r.y + r.z*r.z)`.  However when I run the numbers I'm getting -8.5496e-13 which matches the value you got with Python but not the magnitude.  I'd suggest printing out every single step to see the exact values so you know exactly what is happening.

Comment: @juharr Apparently `np.linalg.norm` returns the **magnitude** of the vector, not the actual unit vector as was my previous assumption. I've substituted `r.normalized.x`, y, and z for `r.magnitude`, and `Two_Body_Ode` now produces the correct result. I always thought that a normalized vector is one which retains its direction but has its magnitude set to 0 (each dimension is divided by the magnitude) and I'm sure this is still correct but it seems I misunderstood what exactly the acceleration equation called for. Thank you for your suggestions!